# how to appoint a UItapGesture recognizer to a CGpoint for a button

Tags: swift, timer, action, uigesturerecognizer

I am creating a game ad i am having a hard time creating a jump button. I have created the jump up and fall down SKaction sequence which works perfect here is how it works.

```
func JumpArrow () {
    self.addChild(jumpArrow)
    jumpArrow.position = CGPointMake(60, 145)
    jumpArrow.xScale = 1
    jumpArrow.yScale = 1
}

func heroJumpMovement () {
    let heroJumpAction = SKAction.moveToY(hero.position.y + 85, 
    duration: 0.5)
    let heroFallAction = SKAction.moveToY(hero.position.y , duration:
    0.5)

    let jumpWait:SKAction = SKAction.waitForDuration(CFTimeInterval(1)) 

    let heroMovementSequence:SKAction = 
    SKAction.sequence([heroJumpAction, heroFallAction ,jumpWait])
    hero.runAction(heroMovementSequence)

}
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent
event:UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches {

        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let node = nodeAtPoint(location)

if node == jumpArrow {

           heroJumpMovement()
 }
```

however, I have a problem. if you quickly tap the button the player will fly off the screen. I hope that i can create a UItapGestureRecognizer and create a delay for the tap so you can't tap the button 2-4 times per second you will only be able to tap it once. If this is the wrong way to go about this please tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a delay would be the wrong way to go about it.

Instead, in your *touchesBegan* function, before you call *heroJumpMovement()* you should **check to see if your player is on the ground or not**.

Another alternative would be to check if the last jump SKActionSequence has **completed or not**.

To do the above, you would have something like this (code not checked):

```
var canJump = true; // Variable will be true if we can jump

func JumpArrow () {
    self.addChild(jumpArrow)
    jumpArrow.position = CGPointMake(60, 145)
    jumpArrow.xScale = 1
    jumpArrow.yScale = 1
}

func heroJumpMovement () {
    let heroJumpAction = SKAction.moveToY(hero.position.y + 85, 
    duration: 0.5)
    let heroFallAction = SKAction.moveToY(hero.position.y , duration:
    0.5)

    let jumpWait:SKAction = SKAction.waitForDuration(CFTimeInterval(1)) 

    let heroMovementSequence:SKAction = 
    SKAction.sequence([heroJumpAction, heroFallAction ,jumpWait])
canJump = false; // We are about to jump so set this to false
    hero.runAction(heroMovementSequence, completion: {canJump = true;}) // Set the canJump variable back to true after we have landed

}
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent
event:UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches {

        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let node = nodeAtPoint(location)

if node == jumpArrow {
          if (canJump) { // Make sure we are allowed to jump
           heroJumpMovement()
          }
 }
```

Notice the **canJump** variable.